Swift App using Shortcuts: Couldn't communicate with helper application
I'm creating an app that takes in apple pay transaction data via the Shortcuts API. So when the shortcuts app is notified that a transaction has occurred, my app should receive the transaction data.
Currently, I have it working where my shortcuts intent is able to be manually triggered from within the shortcuts application by running the intent. Data goes through to the app as intended.
I get the error mentioned in the title when I try to trigger this intent via automation. Shortcuts tells me Couldn't communicate with helper application.
Here's my AppIntent definition:
import Foundation
import AppIntents
import SwiftData

struct AddTransaction: AppIntent {
    @Parameter(title: "Category")
    var intentCategoryEntity: CategoryEntity
    
    @Parameter(title: "TransactionAmount")
    var intentTransaction: IntentCurrencyAmount
    
    @Parameter(title: "TransactionDescription")
    var intentTransactionDescription: String?
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Add Transaction to Category"
    
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Add \(\.$intentTransaction) to \(\.$intentCategoryEntity)") {
            \.$intentTransactionDescription
        }
    }
    
    func perform() async throws -> some ProvidesDialog {
        let backgroundContext = ModelContext(Cashback_DeciderApp.sharedModelContainer)
        let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<CurrentSchema.Category>()
        
        let attemptedCategoryFetch = try backgroundContext
            .fetch(descriptor)
            .first { category in category.id == intentCategoryEntity.id }
        guard let category = attemptedCategoryFetch else {
            throw AddTransactionError.fetchCategoryFailed
        }
        
        let transaction = CurrentSchema.Transaction(date: .now, amount: intentTransaction.amount, note: intentTransactionDescription ?? "")
        category.addTransaction(transaction: transaction)
        
        try backgroundContext.save()
        return .result(dialog: "\(category.spendDescription)")
    }
    
    enum AddTransactionError: Error {
        case fetchCategoryFailed
    }
}

I can provide more code if need be, but I don't think anything else will be particularly helpful off the top of my head.
